# How can I close a TabControlEx tab with the middle mouse button?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

I'm working with the WPF TabControlEx (close tabs).

I'm looking a way to close the tab clicking the tab header with the mouse wheel click.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your XAML on the tab header:

```
<Grid.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding MouseAction="MiddleClick" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" />
</Grid.InputBindings>
```

Have your `CloseCommand` on your ViewModel close the tab. You might also need to pass the specific tab in with the `CommandParameter`.

Answer (score 0):

The Project i was developing was for different purpose but it had the closable tabs if you want to use it you can find it in this [forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/dbadaece-a929-4246-ae34-c16d882f38d5)